# Pass different enums to a method according to generic type

Tags: c#, generics, enums

is it possible to pass enum as parameter to a generic function? In the code below I want CreateInstance function to get the enum parameter according to generic type given. Sample code explains the question better:

```
public class DrivedA
{
    public string myfieldA{get;set;}
    public enum DrivedA_Attributes {
       A,
       B,
       C,
    }

    public void Set(params DerivedClassExtraParameters<DrivedA>[] p)
    {
        //some code
    }
}

public class DrivedB
{
     public string myfieldB { get; set; }
     public enum DrivedB_Attributes
     {
         D,
         E,
         F,
     }

     public void Set(params DerivedClassExtraParameters<DrivedB>[] p)
     {
         //some code
     }
 }

 public class DerivedClassExtraParameters<T>
 {
     internal object myFieldD;
     internal string myName;
     static public DerivedClassExtraParameters<T> CreateInstance(Enum name,  object value)
     {
         DerivedClassExtraParameters<T> instance = new DerivedClassExtraParameters<T>();
         instance.myFieldD = value;
         instance.myName = name.ToString();
         return instance;
     }
 }

 public class TestClass
 {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         DerivedClassExtraParameters<DrivedB> pB = DerivedClassExtraParameters<DrivedB>.CreateInstance(DrivedB.DrivedB_Attributes.D,"1");

         DrivedB b = new DrivedB();
         b.Set(pB);

         //Line #X, I want this line to give error since DerivedClassExtraParameters<DrivedA>.CreateInstance function should get DrivedA.DrivedA_Attributes enum as parameter, not DrivedB.DrivedB_Attributes.
         DerivedClassExtraParameters<DrivedA> pA =      DerivedClassExtraParameters<DrivedA>.CreateInstance(DrivedB.DrivedB_Attributes.D, "1");

         DrivedA a = new DrivedA();
         a.Set(pA);
     }

 }
```

Comment: do you mean `static public DerivedClassExtraParameters<T,TEnum> CreateInstance(TEnum name,  object value)` ?

Comment: coder may not know which enum to use and I want to prevent run time errors. I dont want to use another generics (TEnum), I want the system to understand the correct enum from the class type (T). Is it possible or I can achieve the same functionality with another approach?

Comment: What's the purpose of these enums?

Comment: they include field names of the model class.

Comment: @platon: your explanation doesn't explain anything. :) could you post an example, how do you plan to use descendants of `DerivedClassExtraParameters<T>`?

Comment: @platon possibly worth a look on T4

Comment: I will look over that, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using generics the wrong way. You should try this.

```
 public class DerivedClassExtraParameters<T>
 {
     internal T myFieldD;
     internal string myName;
     static public DerivedClassExtraParameters<T> CreateInstance(T value)
     {
         DerivedClassExtraParameters<T> instance = new DerivedClassExtraParameters<T>();
         instance.myFieldD = value;
         instance.myName = value.GetType().Name;
         return instance;
     }
 }
```

You don't even need the static CreateInstance method. You could just do this

```
public class DerivedClassExtraParameters<T>
     {
         internal T myFieldD;
         internal string myName;

         public DerivedClassExtraParameters(T value)
         {
              myFieldD = value;
              myName = value.GetType().Name;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution but not the solution of my problem. Please check the main method. The coder knows anything about the DerivedClassExtraParameters class, he just knows for which class (DrivedA or DrivedB, in the real project there are lots of them) he has to create it. Therefor I want to give a compile error if he use the wrong enum.

Comment: If you use my implementation, your line will throw a compile error. Indeed DerivedClassExtraParameters<DrivedA>.CreateInstance in my implementation will only accept parameter of type DrivedA. What more do you wish?

Comment: it should take DrivedA.DrivedA_Attributes as parameter, not DrivedA.

Comment: All right, I do understand now :p The only way you can do that is with Grundy solution of adding another type parameter

Comment: Thank you very much, I am not strict, every solution will be appreciated.